# How to create copy of object without any reference and values in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects, it can be a list of integer, string, or class objects.

- If I am getting a list of integer (value-type) it should add a null value at the 0 index.
- If it contains a model object(reference-type), it should contain an object of the same type but the values need to be null.

For example: I am getting the Student data in the list

var sampleList = new Student({Id = 1, Name = "ABC"}, {Id = 2, Name = "CDE"});

Now I have to add a object in the beginning like this {Id= null, Name =null}

So eventually the samplelist will have

{Id= null, Name =null}

{Id = 1, Name = "ABC"}

{Id = 2, Name = "CDE"}

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code.

Comment: first, this has nothing to do with Xamarin or ASP.NET.  It's just a pure C#/.NET question.  Second, a `List<int>` can't contain a null.  Finally, look at the C# `default` keyword

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish, but if it's just adding element to the index 0 (beginning) of the list just use `Insert(0, object)`

Answer (score 0):

If your Target framework is 2.1, then the default C# language version 8.0 can support nullable reference types.Then you can use them like:

```
public class Student
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }
            public string? Name { get; set; }
                public Student()
            { 
            
            }
        }
    } 


public List<Student>? Data;
Data = new List<Student>();
            Student s=new Student();
            s.Id = null;
            s.Name = null;
            Student s2 = new Student();
            s2.Name = "student2";
            s2.Id = 2;
            Data.Add(s);
            Data.Add(s2);
```

Comment: It's not about Student specifcally, it can be a list of books, students, or courses. We do not have info about the type.

Comment: It's a example, if you define it with nullable reference, it can be null.